# How to scroll TableView to top

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This seems like it should be simple but there's no `ScrollTo` method on TableView as ListView has.

How can I scroll a TableView to the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Forms' TableView is not designed to be controlled like a scrolling view, even though they are natively implemented using scrollable containers.

While a custom renderer would be my preferred choice to expose the scrolling features due to Effects overhead, a quick `PlatformEffect` hack using `MessagingCenter` will work as a demo:

On Android, a Forms' TableView uses a `Android.Widget.ListView` as its top level container, so `ListView.SmoothScrollToPosition` can be used.

#### Android PlatformEffect (using MessagingCenter)

```
public class ScrollTopEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    void ScrollToTop(TableView obj)
    {
        (Control as AListView).SmoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (Element is TableView)
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TableView>(Element as TableView, "ScrollTop", ScrollToTop);
        else
            throw new Exception("ScrollTopEffect must be used on a TableView (Android.Widget.ListView)");
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<TableView>(Element as TableView, "ScrollTop");
    }
}
```

#### Xamarin.Forms Usage:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<TableView>(tableView, "ScrollTop");
```

Note: The instance `tableView` var needs to be the one that you wish to scroll to top.

On iOS, Forms uses a `UITableView` as the top container for TableView, so you can use `UITableView.SetContentOffset`` to scroll to top.

#### iOS PlatformEffect (using MessagingCenter)

```
public class ScrollTopEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    void ScrollToTop(TableView obj)
    {
        (Control as UITableView).SetContentOffset(CGPoint.Empty, true);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (Element is TableView)
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TableView>(Element as TableView, "ScrollTop", ScrollToTop);
        else
            throw new Exception("ScrollTopEffect must be used on a TableView (UIkit.UITableView)");
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<TableView>(Element as TableView, "ScrollTop");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to manually remove the Effect from a control in order to reach OnDetached()?

Comment: @EvZ Yes, you would. I'm not a big fan of PlatformEffects due to the design issues like this, even when the page that contains the controls and effects are GC'd, `OnDetached` is not called, effects basically **lives for the life of the app** at that point as the finalizer is never called either..

Comment: Thats right, I try to avoid them as well. Though it will be good to let the community know about those issues.

Comment: When should the Effect be removed?